# TableViewController's cells from .plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I am currently making a tableView for my app, and I've got my cells from a .plist file. However I want to be able to enter my second view controller no matter, what cell I click on, the difference should be that the UIText for my second viewController will depend on which cell I click.

So far, I have imagined something like;

```
   if(tableview.tag == 1){
   myUIText.text = @"a";
   }else if(tableview.tag == 2){
   myUIText.text = @"b";
   etc.......
```

Will this work using the same view controller, same UIText? If not, then how?

And how can I set the tags for my array in my .plist file?

I would appreciate your answers

EDIT: Here is a sample of two methods;

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [self.items count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
 NSString * id = @"plistdata";

   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:id forIndexPath:indexPath];

   if(cell == nil){
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:id];
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should at least add your plist to question

Answer (score 0):

More information is certainly needed by I will make some assumptions on your code and see if it helps any.  I assume the the text you want to send is the title of the cell the person clicked on.  Now how you send that to the next VC will differ depending on if you are using a segue or not.  If you are using a segue you can do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
    UpcomingViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    viewController.textView.text = cell.chapterText;
}
}
```

However if you are using didSelectRowAtIndexPath then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UpcomingViewController *viewController = [[UpcomingViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.textView.text = self.arrayOfChapterText[indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now again because your question wasn't very clear on your scenarios I have taken some liberties with what I think you are probably trying to do.  I assume that the view controller that will show after you choose an item will have the UITextView as a public property so that you can set it before pushing or segueing to your new view.  I also assume in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath that you are using a UINavigationController.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry that I was very unclear. I hope this will help: I have a tableViewController with cells in it, and I have already named the cells using a plist. Cell one may be Chapter 1, cell two may be Chapter 2 etc. What I want to is that when I click on cell 1 (which is Chapter 1) then the UITextView of my second viewController will be set to a text equaling @"a", and if I click on my second cell (which is Chapter 2) then the UITextView of my second viewController (it is the same viewController) will be set to a text equaling @"b". What I want is that I want to use a single viewController

Comment: For all my chapters, so I don't have to create hundreds of viewControllers if I will for instance make a book app. I hope that this really helps

Comment: Yes, I will use a navigationController from the StoryBoard to be able to go back again, if that is what you meant.

Comment: I think I understand.  So you want whatever Chapter number it is to directly link to a letter in the alphabet?  So Chapter 1 is A and Chapter 26 is Z?  What happens if you have more than 26 chapters?  Also you are losing me on this same and second view controller talk.  Are you saying that you want the UITableView to just refresh with new data and not actually transition to a new view controller?

Comment: I am sorry again that I really confused you.No I do not mean Chapter 1 is A.I want to update my viewController according to which cell I have clicked on.If I click on Chapter 1,it will show the text of Chapter 1 which may be:Tom met daddy.And if I click Chapter 2,then my(UITextView in my viewController)have to be updated to:His daddy gave him candy.These are just examples,I want to update/refresh my UITextView in my viewController.I have one tableViewController and one viewController, and when you click on cell from tableViewController it will show my viewController with the updated UITextView

Comment: Ignore my last edit I just saw you have an array of Items.  What is the structure of that array?  I assume it is just Chapter titles?  If so create a second one with chapter text and then you can do:
viewController.textView.text = self.arrayOfChapterText[indexPath.row];

Comment: Hmm that sounds good. But is it possible to write in that array \n to start a new line? And how do I programmatically say that when you click on a cell, it should enter another viewController, else I do not know where to put that new array, if I can handle that

Comment: Correct for each NSString in the NSArray you format it how you like using \n for new lines.  If you look at the code above I explain the transition to a new viewController.  Essentially on your viewController with the UITextView do you have that set as a @Property in your .h file?  If not link that UITextView from the storyboard to your .h file and name whatever you like.  Then follow the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath renaming variables as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. I will look at it tomorrow and come back here again, as it is very late now and I have to rest. See you hopefully tomorrow!

Comment: I tried my best but I did not figure it out. How can I easily say that when I click on cell one (which is Chapter 1), then it pushes me to next viewController (which I already did on storyboard) where the UITextView will have the text set by me as UITextView.text = @"This is the first chapter"; --- And likewise; if I click on Chapter 2 then it pushes me to next viewController where the UITextView is set by me as UITextView.text = @"This is the second chapter"; -- I think this could easily be done by buttons, for I could create a method that said when you click on the button, the text will be

Comment: such and such. Can't i programmatically do this with cells also? For buttons, you could just do -(void)btn1Clicked{ viewController.UITextView.text = @"This is chapter One"; and I could just create other methods for the other buttons. Can't this really be done by cells also - programmatically?